# Two Controllers for one view in Ruby on Rails with mongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

can we have two controller rendered into one view in Ruby on Rails?
Example:
I has two controller with names:
`studentData_controller.rb` and
`teacherData_controller.rb`
as the actions names for both of them are same.That is create,update,show and delete data related to student,teachers(but logic inside them is different).

> Example:
>
> pay is a method in both the controllers but with different logics as:
> In teacherData_controller:pay show check the pay range between some 20k to 50k
> Whereas for studentData_controller pay should check for range between 100k to 200k.

As both has same field.I am using same model.Does rendering two controller with single view cause any performance issues or any security related problems.

Answer (score 2):

That's just not how Rails works.

The request comes in from Rack to the router which looks up a controller and action which matches the request url and format.

Rails will then pass the request to the single controller. It will never call two controllers.

If the goal is to share code between between controllers - use concerns or some other flavor of inheritance or mixins.

Two controllers can render the same view (on different requests) - but usually if you find yourself doing this you should instead put the shared code into partials instead of creating a really convoluted view.

### PS

You should follow the Ruby (and rails) naming conventions for files / classes / modules.

If your controller is named `TeacherDataController` than the file should be:

`teacher_data_controller.rb`. Failing to do so will cause issues with the way Rails autoloads files. Plus you'll never get to sit with the cool kids.

Answer (score 2):

No , you can't use two controller for a single request with a single view. If you want to access code from two different functions , then make the two functions in a helper/module with their business logic, include that Helper in your controller & call the two functions in the same controller.